# Sweedler's notation and commutators of Hopf subalgebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be a cocommutative $K$-Hopf algebra, where $K$ is a field. Given Hopf subalgebras $X,Y$, one can define the commutator of $X,Y$ to be the subalgebra $[X,Y]$ of $A$ generated by the elements
$$\{x,y\}=x_1y_1S(x_2)S(y_2),$$
where $x\in X$, $y\in Y$, $S$ is the antipode of $A$, and we are using Sweedler's notation. In the recent paper "[A semi-abelian extension of a theorem by Takeuchi](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002240491930012X)", it is showed that $[X,Y]$ is a Hopf subalgebra of $A$, normal if $X,Y$ are normal.

In the proof, to show that $[X,Y]$ is invariant under comultiplication $\Delta$, the following few lines of computation are presented:

$$\Delta(x_1y_1S(x_2)S(y_2))=x_1y_1S(x_4)S(y_4)\otimes x_2y_2S(x_3)S(y_3)\\
=x_1y_1S(x_2)S(y_2)\otimes x_3y_3S(x_4)S(y_4)\in [X,Y]\otimes [X,Y].
$$

I am not understanding this proof, and in particular its "shortness". I think I can prove the result, but I need at least one page of computation, based on the fact that as $A$ is cocommutative, we have the equality $(\Delta_{A\otimes_K A})\Delta=(\Delta\otimes\Delta)\Delta$. However, for sure there there is something clever that I am missing in the proof above, probably in the use of Sweedler's notation. Could you please give me some indication to understand why this proof work?

Comment: I like to use a prime and double prime for $$\Delta(x)=\sum_{(x)}x’\otimes x’’$$. You should look at an introductory book that teaches in his notation, like Kassel’s book.

Comment: The proof is correct, btw. The second equal sign is a consequence of commutativity, and that the last tensor is where it is claimed to be could probably be made more clear by adding an extra step. For example, if we write [x,y] the commutator x1.y1.S(x2).S(y2), then the last tensor is equal to [x1,y1]\otimes[x2,y2]

Comment: I am sure it is, but I really don't see it at the moment.

Comment: If possible, I still would love to have a couple of more comments enlightening the use of Sweedler’s notation…